# Import gives error "Could not find module `Data.List.Split`"

Tags: haskell

I am using haskell 9.2.4 and I'm trying to import `Data.List.Split` because I want to use the `splitOn` function for my code.

```
GHCi, version 9.2.4: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
ghci> :l Program   -- my program imports Data.List.Split
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Program.hs, interpreted )

Program.hs:1:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘Data.List.Split’
    Use -v (or `:set -v` in ghci) to see a list of the files searched for.
  |
1 | import Data.List.Split
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

This is the error I'm getting when I'm trying to load my program.
Earlier I imported `Data.List` which worked fine for using the `filter` function.

*Update:* when I try to import `Data.List` and `Data.Text` it now marks my `filter` function as an error.  I am on Mac btw.

Comment: Update: when I try to import Data.List and Data.Text it now marks my filter function as an error.

I am on mac btw

Answer (score 2):

The [`Data.List.Split` module](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/split-0.2.3.5/docs/Data-List-Split.html) is defined in the [`split` package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/split/), you thus first install that package, for example with `cabal`:

```
cabal install split
```

If you import `Data.Text`, then this module exports a (different) `filter` function, hence that will result in ambiguity. You can for example import `Data.Text` as `T` and then work with `T.filter` if you need that function:

```
import qualified Data.Text as T
```